# Temporary table in postgres causing Lockmanager high in postgres 12 RDS

Tags: postgresql

There is no reason to lock Temporary table in postgres as life time of temp table is single session only, no possibility of concurrent TX's. It looks "on commit drop" may reduce the locking mechanism. Any reason why Temp table locking in postgres.

On commit drop may help to reduce locks

Comment: 1) A temporary table is still a relation/table, so locking can happen for the same reasons it does on any other table. Concurrent transactions are not necessary for locking to occur, Think in single transaction `select  * from some_table ... for update;` and then some other action on `some_table`. 2) What is the actual problem you are having? **Add information as update to question**.

Comment: Locking temporary tables seems unnecessary, but it might be unnecessarily complicated to handle them differently. I don't know if you are hitting an Amazon-generated bug here, but I cannot imagine how locks on a temporary table can be a problem. Your question does, however, not contain enough detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LaurenzAlbe,we both are on same page, I see "Lockmanager" is taking high CPU after creating temp table in 500 TPS function. Just checking is there any other reason or this temp table causes lockmanager.This is remote machine not having access to check exactly .As per history is concern Lockmanager increased after adding temp table in function.

Comment: You should describe in more detail what exactly the function does; perhaps show part of the code.

Comment: Does this; *...creating temp table in 500 TPS function* mean you are creating 500 temporary tables per second?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver,yes as CTE is not performing well